# How to unmount after using mount --bind option?

Tags: filesystem, files

I have mounted a hard disk `/dev/sda1` on `/media/backup`. Further, I have issued the following command:

```
mkdir /home/users/Desktop/backup
sudo mount --bind /media/backup /home/users/Desktop/backup
```

This allows me to access `/media/backup` from `/home/users/Desktop/backup` as well. However, now I would like to remove the `--bind` from `/home/users/Desktop/backup`. How should I go about doing this correctly?

Do I simply remove the `/home/users/Desktop/backup` directory? Or should I be using `umount`?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`umount /home/users/Desktop/backup` will remove the bind between the 2 folders.

You can then check `/home/users/Desktop/backup` to make sure that the bind is gone and remove the folder if you wish.

Comment: `df` is a nice command to test that. `df /home/users/Desktop/backup` should give different output when mounted and unmounted.

Comment: consider `mountpoint` and `findmnt`